# ISOTOPE: Sort by a category and by date

Tags: jquery, sorting, posts, jquery-isotope

I'm using [ISOTOPE](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/sorting.html) and have 6 categories. Each category will have any number of posts.

I have a list of links to each category, when a category name is clicked (for example: Artists) I need all boxes within that artists category to be moved to the top and ordered by date, the most recent box displayed first.

In my JS file I have this:

```
$container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.module',
    getSortData : {
      artists : function( $elem ) {
        return $elem.attr('artists');
      }
    }
  });
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="module artists" data-category="artists">
<p class="date">01/02/12</p>
<img src="../url.jpg" />
<p>Link title</p>
</div>
```

This code doesn't seem to sort it the way I want and haven't a clue how to adapt it, could someone help?

Comment: For an answer, head on over to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700295/isotope-select-and-display-xx-class-at-the-top

Answer (score 2):

This is all I really needed to do:

```
getSortData : {
  blogs : function( $elem ) {
    var isBlog = $elem.hasClass('blogs');
    return (isBlog?' ':'') + $elem.find('.date').text();
  }
}
```

For the full answer check out this post: [Isotope: Select and display .xx class at the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700295/isotope-select-and-display-xx-class-at-the-top)