# Isotope: Select and display .xx class at the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-isotope

I'm using the sorting methods within Isotope (http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/sorting.html) and need to display elements with a specific CSS class name assigned to them at the top when a link is clicked. The remaining elements must remain visible beneath the sorted elements so I cannot use Isotope filtering.

I'm not so comfortable with JS/jQuery so I'm not even to sure if this code is even set out correctly but currently my elements are sorting by date which is great, however its doing this for all elements. I would like my code to find all elements with the class name of 'blogs' then arrange by date. This is my code so far:

```
    getSortData : {
      blogs : function( $elem ) {
        return $elem.attr('.blogs'), $elem.find('.date').text();
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isotope does a normal sort based on the returned value of the function you provide.

So you need to return something that puts the `.blog` elements at the top ..

I am assuming that for date only you used `$elem.find('.date').text()`

So to alter this you can just add a space at the beginning for elements that are `.blog`

Try

```
getSortData : {
  blogs : function( $elem ) {
    var isBlog = $elem.hasClass('blogs');
    return (isBlog?' ':'') + $elem.find('.date').text();
  }
}
```

---

**Update for comments**

```
    sortBy: 'initial',
    sortAscending : false,
    itemSelector: '.module',
    getSortData: {
        initial: function($elem) {
            return $elem.find('.date').text();
        },
        blogs: function($elem) {
            var isBlog = $elem.hasClass('blogs');
            return (isBlog ? '9' : '') + $elem.find('.date').text();
        },
```

Comment: Wow, thats working brilliantly...thanks! The only problem now though is that the boxes with the oldest date gets displayed first. To get round this I could put in sortAscending : false within my isotope function but this means old content gets displayed at the top on page load. This is a separate question to the one asked but do you know of a way to get the sortAscending : false option working within the code you've given me above?

Comment: @egr103, not sure i understand the problem.. it should sort as it did before, but moving all `.blog` elements at the top (*sorted between themselves as the rest are*). You do want each group (*the `.blog` and the others to be sorted in their own group, right ?*) Do you have a live version of this ? or can you make a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Everything filters to the top just great so there's nothing wrong with your code. Thanks! The problem is with ordering the boxes by most recent date. Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/93fL2/ Notice when you click on the Blogs link, two boxes (cyan like border) come to the top. The most recent dated box (the box titled 'blog/director') should be top left as it is dated the most recent (20120314). It isn't though as Isotope defaults to sorting boxes in ascending order. I need the boxes to sort in descending order so the most recent dated boxes are displayed first. I hope that makes sense!?

Comment: As I mentioned above I've tried the Isotope option: sortAscending : false which fixes the issue but then it creates another issue in that when the page is refreshed the oldest dated boxes are displayed at the top and the newest are at the bottom, which isn't that useful to a visitor.

Comment: @egr103, i got it.. You should set the `sortAscending` to `false` like you say, but instead of using a space at the start of the dates, use something that is larger than all the numbers. for example changing the space to `9` (*or any ascii char which comes after the digits used in the date*) will fix it. **[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/93fL2/2/)**

Comment: Thanks for all your effort on this one! Boxes are displaying great when you sort by category but the most recently dated boxes are still displaying at the bottom when the page is refreshed, is there anyway of getting them to display at the top as well? Thanks again!

Comment: @egr103, sure.. you can create and additional sort group (*lets name it `initial`*) and use that for the initial sorting by using the `sortBy` option. `sortBy : 'initial'` **[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/93fL2/4/)**

Comment: Huge thanks for your help thats worked a treat! Beyond the call of service! Cheers!